# Conditional types based on string union fail with error 2344

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a conditional type based on a string union type, but I'm having an error 2344 with the latest option in the conditional type.

```js
// Those are available column types.
export type ColumnType =
    | "boolean"
    | "calculated"
    | "country"
    | "date"
    | "enum"
    | "int"
    | "language"
    | "price"
    | "string"

// This is a template interface only used for creating column's types bellow, it won't be used elsewhere.
interface ColumnTemplate<Type extends ColumnType> {
    id: string
    title: string
    type: Type
}

// Some column's types will have extra fiels (calculated & enum)
type CalculatedColumn<ItemType> = ColumnTemplate<"calculated"> & {
    resolver: (item: ItemType) => string | null
}

type EnumColumn = ColumnTemplate<"enum"> & {
    dictionary: Map<string, string>
}

type OtherType = Exclude<ColumnType, "calculated" | "enum">
type OtherColumn<Type extends OtherType> = ColumnTemplate<Type>

// This is our final column type that we want to use.
export type Column<ItemType, Type extends ColumnType> = Type extends "calculated"
    ? CalculatedColumn<ItemType>
    : Type extends "enum"
    ? EnumColumn
    : OtherColumn<Type>
//                ^^^^ Error is here
```

The error is at the last line:

```
Type 'Type' does not satisfy the constraint 'OtherType'.
  Type 'ColumnType' is not assignable to type 'OtherType'.
    Type '"calculated"' is not assignable to type 'OtherType'.(2344)
```

The `OtherColumn<Type>` should not be `"calculated"` since this type should resolve to `CalculatedColumn`...

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsHsGcFNQEMBOikDckEsA2SAjXRAY2lwFcBbAO1ABcBPAB3lgDoBYAKHgA9m0FPQYtEAYXLUa4MaAC8PUMtAAfUACIC0cvCQ0NSleo0kkuEhXz14AE0PcVazWQo16KRg6cnbSG97GmvA01IHKJtju4c4a+DQA5hRICfAxJswo2CRpRhGasB5RCQ48IBCQ2LCgVcgM8FTM1ohRNigAZkg5oNA0uIygFAi2oO1CoCRo-sUTUrQA5NVMrNUE8Li40ADuADQ1Ilu98yJrg8Og6whbkPBoXNytt53dkpS04A1N-vAAPLKsFz4Nhotmqr2k-3gAD5QABvPI1WwALlAhSyiQR9Gw9GIKLRxUxYhRkJ4AF8eGUwABlaBUUhzGiLUQrUBbPC4UCQTCIfgeJCjbCXUAACjMFis3xGADILqEqABKHjLCTmSzNWzg2g-ACSNiokJh8lAmpkn2aP1MqolNnsMJl8McKjQsHIGFuKOF2IaKN1DUh8oUMPxiWcoQ2ZIp3GVoAAonKTQpjQyPo1zRoQmE7XCEbZsljeqhGCiALJIZg-YMJPaVqER7hKuQAeXoNxQkMTMb4JEotl+Jshe0t4vVGliGaoGlrUabLduJr+cl5IVBoGbrYNif7Zu+C9YU8pFVqtWgFBQApo5lmbzo0Zb-lZiC2+hE9GgZ3g934gmEzIkDJ1eoDhAi5AsuYLJmIhrAQCS4gtUQ5qpKMQAPzGla6rzr6+qQQixIgcCK7pnKKGxvGDK4aus4oPOBpAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional types aren't always as powerful as we want them to be! In this case the `Type` in the final line is effectively narrowed to `Exclude<ColumnType, "enum">` because of the inner conditional, rather than `Exclude<Exclude<ColumnType, "enum">, "calculated">` which we might expect in that nested context.

You can work around it by re-ordering a little:

```js
export type Column<ItemType, Type extends ColumnType> =
    Type extends OtherType
        ? OtherColumn<Type>
        : Type extends "calculated"
            ? CalculatedColumn<ItemType>
            : EnumColumn
```

This works because `EnumColumn` doesn't depend on `Type`.

Alternatively, you could narrow the type explicitly with an intersection:

```js
export type Column<ItemType, Type extends ColumnType> =
    Type extends "calculated"
        ? CalculatedColumn<ItemType>
        : Type extends "enum"
            ? EnumColumn
            : OtherColumn<Type & OtherType>
```